# Is it possible to pull a webpage or content from the web into a widget on the android home screen?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

I have a php web page that will randomize an image that is 158 x 154.  I was able to get the android application to work, but would also like to get it to work as a widget.  How can I get a widget to pull information from the net?

I got the widget to work and layout correctly with a black sample image.  I have tried to look at the wiki sample, but it is a bit too complicated for me to grasp.  The data that gets pulled looks something like:

```
<html><body bgcolor="#000000">center>    
<a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">
<img border="0" src="http://www.webiste.com//0.gif"></a>
<img src="http://www.webiste.com" style="border:none;" />
</center></body></html>
```

Comment: Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html) fetching and displaying remote images.

Answer (score 2):

> How the heck can I get a widget to
>   pull information from the net?

In your `RemoteViews`, try calling `setImageViewUri()` supplying the ID of the `ImageView` widget in the app widget's layout and the URL to the image as converted to a `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you.  I just feel really dumb.  Here is what I have so far.  Of course it doesn't work.  Think my brain has turned to mush.

java
package com.domanin.file;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class QuotesWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
 void addView(int, RemoteViews);
 setImageViewUri(widget);
 
}